# will mongodb index work on looked up collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

assume I have collection A like:

```
A{
  b: bid
}
```

and collection B with index on field x

assume I do an aggregation on A like:

```
{ $lookup from B as b where b._id = a.bid}
{ $match b.x = something}
```

will the index on B improve query?

Comment: Not like that since it's matching on an array within the document and not the collection. Put an `$unwind` directly after the `$lookup` and before the `$match` and it actually will. Look at the "explain" output to see why.

Comment: See [Aggregate $lookup Total size of documents in matching pipeline exceeds maximum document size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726501/2313887)

Comment: https://de.slideshare.net/mongodb/doing-joins-in-mongodb-best-practices-for-using-lookup - in particular slide 16