# add fields where condition match to nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following `users` collection

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afadfdf08a7aa6f1a27d986"),
    "firstName" : "bruce",
    "friends" : [ ObjectId("5afd1c42af18d985a06ac306"),ObjectId("5afd257daf18d985a06ac6ac") ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afbfe21daf4b13ddde07dbe"),
    "firstName" : "clerk",
    "friends" : [],
}]
```

and have `friends` collection

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afd1c42af18d985a06ac306"),
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5afaab572c4ec049aeb0bcba"),
    "requester" : ObjectId("5afadfdf08a7aa6f1a27d986"),
    "status" : 2,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afd257daf18d985a06ac6ac"),
    "recipient" : ObjectId("5afadfdf08a7aa6f1a27d986"),
    "requester" : ObjectId("5afbfe21daf4b13ddde07dbe"),
    "status" : 1,
}]
```

suppose I have an user logged in with `_id: "5afaab572c4ec049aeb0bcba"` and this `_id` matches the `recipient` of the `friends`

Now I have to add a field `friendsStatus` which contains the `status` from `friends` collection... And if does not matches the any `recipient` from the array then its status should be `0`

So when I get all users then my output should be

```
[{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5afadfdf08a7aa6f1a27d986"),
        "firstName" : "bruce",
        "friends" : [ ObjectId("5afd1c42af18d985a06ac306") ],
        "friendStatus": 2
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5afbfe21daf4b13ddde07dbe"),
        "firstName" : "clerk",
        "friends" : [],
        "friendStatus": 0
}]
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have MongoDB 3.6 then you can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with a "sub-pipeline"

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Friend.collection.name,
    "let": { "friends": "$friends" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "recipient": ObjectId("5afaab572c4ec049aeb0bcba"),
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$friends" ] }
      }},
      { "$project": { "status": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "friends"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "friends": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$friends",
        "in": "$$this._id"
      }
    },
    "friendsStatus": {
      "$ifNull": [ { "$min": "$friends.status" }, 0 ]
    }
  }}
])
```

For earlier versions, it's ideal to actually use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in order to ensure you don't breach the [BSON Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/):

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Friend.collection.name,
    "localField": "friends",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "friends"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$friends", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "friends.recipient": ObjectId("5afaab572c4ec049aeb0bcba") },
      { "friends": null }
    ]
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "firstName": { "$first": "$firstName" },
    "friends": { "$push": "$friends._id" },
    "friendsStatus": {
      "$min": { 
        "$ifNull": ["$friends.status",0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

There is *"one difference"* from the most *optimal* form here in that the pipeline optimization does not actually "roll-up" the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) condition into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) itself:

```
{
  "$lookup" : {
    "from" : "friends",
    "as" : "friends",
    "localField" : "friends",
    "foreignField" : "_id",
    "unwinding" : {
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
    }
  }
},
{
  "$match" : {   // <-- outside will preserved array
```

Because of the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option being `true` then the *"fully optimized"* action where the condition would actually be applied to the foreign collection *"before"* results are returned does not happen.

So the only purpose of `unwinding` here is purely to avoid what would normally be a target "array" from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result causing the parent document to grow beyond the BSON Limit. Additional conditions of the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) are then applied "after" this stage. The default [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) without the option presumes `false` for the preservation and a `matching` condition is added instead to do this. This of course would result in the documents with no foreign matches being excluded.

And not really advisable because of that [BSON Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/), but there is also applying [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to the resulting array of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Friend.collection.name,
    "localField": "friends",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "friends"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "friends": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$friends",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$this.recipient",
                ObjectId("5afaab572c4ec049aeb0bcba")
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "in": "$$this._id"
      }
    },
    "friendsStatus": {
      "$ifNull": [
        { "$min": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$friends",
                "cond": {
                   "$eq": [
                     "$$this.recipient",
                      ObjectId("5afaab572c4ec049aeb0bcba")
                   ]
                }
              }
            },
            "in": "$$this.status"
          }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

In either case we're basically adding the "additional condition" to the join being not just on the directly related field but also with the additional constraint of the queried `ObjectId` value for `"recipient"`.

Not really sure what you are expecting for `"friendsStatus"` since the result is an array and there can possibly be more than one ( as far as I know ) and therefore just applying [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) here to extract one value from the array in either case.

The governing condition in each case is [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) which is applied where there isn't anything in the `"friends"` output array to extract from and then you simply return the result of `0` where that is the case.

All output the same thing:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5afadfdf08a7aa6f1a27d986"),
        "firstName" : "bruce",
        "friends" : [
                ObjectId("5afd1c42af18d985a06ac306")
        ],
        "friendsStatus" : 2
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5afbfe21daf4b13ddde07dbe"),
        "firstName" : "clerk",
        "friends" : [ ],
        "friendsStatus" : 0
}
```

Comment: `$lookup argument 'unwinding: { preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }' must be a string, is type object` when I use `"unwinding" : {
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
    }`

Comment: @AshishChoudhary You don't actually type that in yourself. You're looking at the "explain" output I'm showing. The difference between the code and that output should be pretty clear. See [Aggregate $lookup Total size of documents in matching pipeline exceeds maximum document size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726501/2313887) for the longer explanation.