# Trying to join(look up) two collections using Mongo query but it is throwing me an error

Tags: mongodb

I wrote a mongodb query and trying to join(look up) two collections using Mongo query but it is throwing me an error saying maximum document size exceeds. Same query in running on small collection where 150 documents are there but failing to work on 2.9 million documents. I need help in this.

I am using Studio 3T for MongoDB 2018.6.1 IDE

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "joined_data"
    }
  }
])
```

Unable to execute the selected commands

```
Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 4568 (Location4568): 'Total size of documents in collection2 matching pipeline { $match: { $and: [ { id: { $eq: null } }, {} ] } } exceeds maximum document size' on server 168.152.169.555:27017.
```

The full response is:

```
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "Total size of documents in collection2 matching pipeline { $match: { $and: [ { id: { $eq: null } }, {} ] } } exceeds maximum document size", 
    "code" : NumberInt(4568), 
    "codeName" : "Location4568"
}
```

Comment: The error clearly says that matching documents exceeded the maximum document size i.e. **16mb**.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I understood that but how do I use a 'Lookup' to join the 2 collections which contain around 3 million documents?

Comment: What version of mongo you are using?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB 3.4

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724785/aggregate-lookup-total-size-of-documents-in-matching-pipeline-exceeds-maximum-d/45726501#45726501

Comment: I think this is really helpful for me thank you.