# Total size of documents in matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, size, aggregate, pipeline

I have 2 collections. One for Form Submissions and other for Form Answers.

1. Form Submissions - No of Documents = 17,318
2. Form Answers - No of Documents = 17,191

**Sample data for FormSubmissions.**

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5e27ea5707f2a21cecb0dc77"},
"LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
"FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
"SubscriberId":{"$oid":"5db1278dc6f6570e9121edad"},
"FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f6"},
"FolderName":"7ff60e99-ab67-75d8-d2e7-e2c93f26bcfd",
"IsSync":false,
"UpdatedBy":0,
"IsCompleted":false,
"ProjectId":{"$oid":"5e25966d07f2a21cecb0cd27"},
"ClientId":{"$oid":"5e258f9807f2a21cecb0cd23"},
"LocalInLineId":null,
"ParentSubmissionId":null,
"IsDeleted":true,"UpdatedOn":{"$date":"2020-02-03T07:40:42.626Z"},
"SubmittedOn":{"$date":"2020-01-22T06:23:19.237Z"},
"CreatedOn":{"$date":"2020-01-22T06:23:19.237Z"},
"EmployeeId":{"$oid":"5db12946c6f6570e9121edb2"},
"Longitude":"72.5298174",
"Latitude":"23.0172479",
"DeviceId":"b896c36665a93cb6",
"AppInfoId":null,
"__v":0
}

{
"_id":{"$oid":"5e340be407f2a21cecb2663e"},
"LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
"FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
"SubscriberId":{"$oid":"5db1278dc6f6570e9121edad"},
"FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5e27f4a807f2a21cecb0dcf5"},
"FolderName":"6450638c-0d3f-f406-1a2e-6ca2762a4a40",
"IsSync":false,
"UpdatedBy":0,
"IsCompleted":false,
"ProjectId":{"$oid":"5e25966d07f2a21cecb0cd27"},
"ClientId":{"$oid":"5e258f9807f2a21cecb0cd23"},
"LocalInLineId":null,
"ParentSubmissionId":null,
"IsDeleted":true,
"UpdatedOn":{"$date":"2020-02-03T07:40:55.157Z"},
"SubmittedOn":{"$date":"2020-01-31T11:13:40.410Z"},
"CreatedOn":{"$date":"2020-01-31T11:13:40.410Z"},
"EmployeeId":{"$oid":"5e2fd5a607f2a21cecb15bba"},
"Longitude":"72.5298021",
"Latitude":"23.0172461",
"DeviceId":"b4e958698555a31d",
"AppInfoId":null,
"__v":0
},
```

**and sample data for FormAnswers**

```
    {
    "_id":{"$oid":"5e27ea5707f2a21cecb0dcc1"},
    "FormId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5"},
    "FormVersionId":{"$oid":"5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f6"},
    "FormSubmissionId":{"$oid":"5e27ea5707f2a21cecb0dc77"},
    "LanguageId":{"$oid":"5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"},
    "Answers":[{
            "_id":{"$oid":"5e27ea5707f2a21cecb0dc78"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e27e1b607f2a21cecb0daf5"},
            "ElementType":8,
            "Value":"ABC"
        },
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5e27ea5707f2a21cecb0dc79"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e27e1b607f2a21cecb0daf6"},
            "ElementType":2,
            "Value":"3"
        },
        {
            "_id":{"$oid":"5e27ea5707f2a21cecb0dc7a"},
            "FormQuestionId":{"$oid":"5e27e1b607f2a21cecb0daf7"},
            "ElementType":45,
            "Value":"22012020/114920"
        },],
       "__v":0
}
```

**Here is the query:**

```
db.FormSubmissions.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $and: [{
             FormId: ObjectId('5da7f7dfa6334912bc30a3f5')
           }, 
           {
             IsDeleted: false
           }]
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      submissionIds: {
        $addToSet: '$_id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'FormAnswers',
      localField: 'submissionIds',
      foreignField: 'FormSubmissionId',
      as: 'FormAnswers',
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: null,
      TotalSubmissions: {
        $size: '$FormAnswers',
      },
    },
  },
])
```

**When Execute above query it give below error**

**Total size of documents in FormAnswers matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate $lookup Total size of documents in matching pipeline exceeds maximum document size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724785/aggregate-lookup-total-size-of-documents-in-matching-pipeline-exceeds-maximum-d)

Comment: Add `{ allowDiskUse: true }` to the aggregation.