# How To Solve Max Size Issue In MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to populate other collection by using lookup query but it gives me this error:-

`Total size of documents in images-extractions matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 16793600 bytes`

My database models look like this:-
Images-Extractions Model

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("610109cce690258166ed9ee1"),
   "fileRef":ObjectId("610108e26532080a11417225"), 
   "imageName":"image 1",
   "imageSize":664156,
   // other fields
}
```

File Model:-

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("610108e26532080a11417225"),
   "fileStatus":"ACTIVE",
   // other fields
}
```

I have used this query on file model in aggregation :-

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': ObjectId('610108e26532080a11417225')
    }
  }, 
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'images-extractions', 
      'as': 'imagesExtractions', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': 'fileRef'
    }
  }
]
```

And this query gives me the following error:- `Total size of documents in images-extractions matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 16793600 bytes`

Can anyone help me with this? Please tell me how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724785/aggregate-lookup-total-size-of-documents-in-matching-pipeline-exceeds-maximum-d

Answer (score 0):

Your `$lookup` probably matched too many records. You can follow up your `$lookup` with an `$unwind`. According to [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup----unwind-coalescence),

> When a $unwind immediately follows another $lookup, and the $unwind operates on the as field of the $lookup, the optimizer can coalesce the $unwind into the $lookup stage. This avoids creating large intermediate documents.